# Azure migrate Port requirement

Tags: azure, migrate

I am new to Azure Migrate, we are in process of migrate on-premises virtual server (VMware) to Azure VM.

We have install Agentless appliance and notices that all the performance data missing for all VMs in my assessment report.

with some  research found that it required  that outbound connections on ports 443 (HTTPS) are allowed.

Can someone please help me understand  source and target  between which i need to open port 443

Thanks

suraj

Answer (score 1):

Agentless migration uses the Azure Migrate appliance. You can deploy the appliance as a VMware VM using an OVA template

**Port requirements (agentless)**

1. On Appliance -> we need to open Outbound connections on port 443 to upload replicated data to Azure, and to communicate with Azure Migrate services orchestrating replication and migration
2. On vCenter server -> we need to open Inbound connections on port 443 to allow the appliance to orchestrate replication - create snapshots, copy data, release snapshots
3. On vSphere/ESXI host -> we need to open Inbound on TCP port 902 for the appliance to replicate data from snapshots.

Here is the reference document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/migrate-support-matrix-vmware-migration#vm-requirements-agentless